# How to make a POST value stay forever with in another value?

Tags: php, session

I am making a website editor and I need to make a box where you can type and it will submit it to the page. Now I have done that but when I refresh that page, the value expires and disappears, I have tried making a `SESSION` value and it remained the same problem. Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu   paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="../">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I want to submit it to the index, which it is and save that value forever.

Comment: I tried making the session value = the post

Comment: What do mean by save that value for ever.

Comment: How i want my site to work is in the admin center you can enter anything and it will submit and echo it on the home page. I don't want it where if someone logs on to the site they wont be able to see the information the user just added. with the post it only goes till you refresh it.

Comment: The 'session' is for the current user only. I think you want something to be shown on the 'home' page so that all can be seen by all users next time they visit it? The message will be entered by an 'admin' user? You need to store it somewhere that can be read when the 'home page' is displayed. This is normally the 'database' or a file. i.e. a _'message of the day'_ type facility?

Comment: @RyanVincent that wouldn't work because I'm making it dynamic. Where the user can type in what they want for their homepage and it posts out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to initialize session if you want to keep track of your objects. Then you can save there anything:

```
<?php
  session_start ();
  if(isset($_POST)){
    $_SESSION['content'] = $_POST['content'];
  }
  echo $_SESSION['content'];
?>
```

Comment: Still goes away after refresh

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'proof of concept'. Maybe it will help to clarify what is required?

It is a 'PHP Class' that stores a 'message' in a text file. I provide a couple of 'sample' php files that will 'demonstrate' how to use it.

Rather than post the 'sample' files here, i will provide links to the source files in 'pastebin'. There is a 'test website' where it can be seen working.

[Sample Home Page: AdminMessageDisplay.php](http://pastebin.com/67dv3w5Y)

[Sample Edit Page: AdminMessageForm.php](http://pastebin.com/6XRBj5gH)

[Sample Website](http://rfv123.eu.pn/adminmsg/)

The input is truncated to a fixed length and the output has *`htmlentities`* applied in case a mistake is made when adding the message.

The 'AdminMessage' class... If it needs more documentation then i will gladly provide it. This works on 'Windows' and 'unix' unchanged.

// class to save a message in a file.

```
class AdminMessage {

    const FILE_NAME = 'admin_message.txt';

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->getFilename())) {
            touch($this->getFilename());
        }
    }

    public function getFilename()
    {
        return __DIR__ .'/'. self::FILE_NAME;
    }

    public function setMessage($msg = '')
    {
        file_put_contents($this->getFilename(), $msg);
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return file_get_contents($this->getFilename());
    }
}
```